# unix script run search in parallel

Tags: unix

I have a script that searches files for a phrase in a number of different folders, then shows to output.

The trouble is, it does each search sequentially and takes a long time. I would like to make the searches run without waiting for the previous one to finish.

```
zipped_folders=("/extlogs/archive/rsyslog/folder1/"
                "/extlogs/archive/rsyslog/folder2/")

folders=("/extlogs/rsyslog/Folder1/"
         "/extlogs/rsyslog/Folder2/")

portal=0
mobile=0
email=0

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Incorrect Argument: logcount 201602"
    exit 1
fi

for i in "${zipped_folders[@]}"
do
    #echo $i"syslog-"$1*".log.gz"
    ((portal+=$(nohup gunzip -c $i"syslog-"$1*".log.gz" | grep -i "search1" | grep -v "Search1" | wc -l &)))
    ((mobile+=$(nohup gunzip -c $i"syslog-"$1*".log.gz" | grep -i "Search2" | wc -l &)))
    ((email+=$(nohup gunzip -c $i"syslog-"$1*".log.gz" | grep -i "search3" | grep -v "ActiveSync" | wc -l &)))
done

for i in "${folders[@]}"
do
    ((portal+=$(nohup cat $i"syslog-"$1*".log"| grep -i "search4"| grep -v "exsearch4" | wc -l &)))
    ((mobile+=$(nohup cat $i"syslog-"$1*".log" | grep -i "search5" | wc -l &)))
    ((email+=$(nohup cat $i"syslog-"$1*".log" | grep -i "search6" | grep -v "ActiveSync" | wc -l &)))
done

echo "Portal: " $portal
echo "Mobile: " $mobile
echo "Email: " $email

exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs`.

```
find ${topdir} -name '*.gz' | xargs -n1 -P${PARALLEL_JOBS} -I {} bash -c "/usr/bin/grep 'criteria' {}"
```

Comment: Good, but how dangerous is it to start an unlimited number of parallel processes?

Comment: The number of child processes (AKA the "fanout") is limited per invocation of `xargs`. All you need to do is to make the number of `xargs` invocations limited, for instance by grouping the code that feeds the input for the search in a subshell and feeding it to a single `xargs` as `(find ...; find...; echo "onemore.tgz")|xargs ...`